# Taking screenshots

Tags: screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot Taking Tools](https://superuser.com/questions/88686/screenshot-taking-tools)

I need to take a screen shot of my disk management system.

Comment: How is that different from taking screenshots in general? (And if it's not: 54 answers at [Screenshot Taking Tools](http://superuser.com/questions/88686/screenshot-taking-tools).)

Comment: Odd, I commented within 2 minutes after this vague question was posted, but the question asker has already signed off? Voting to close then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Print screen</kbd> or <kbd>PRTSC</kbd> button that should be on the right side of your F keys at the top of the keyboard.

Then paste into the program you like (Paint, MS Word, etc.) by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: You mean Command-Shift-3 ;-)

Comment: @Arjan on a Mac yes indeed xD